# Clone a git repo on a Linux box

Tags: git

I only have access to a RedHat box through ssh commands that I can connect to it.
Now I want to copy my code from GitHub to that box.

In the browser view of my github I see two things: one for `HTTP` and one for `SSH`.

Does that mean I should use the SSH one?  How?

I have used the HTTP one before by saying `git clone thatHTTPAddrees`

Comment: Have you tried doing *the exact same thing*?

Comment: I did. It says "Fatal:HTTP Request Failed" ... then now I did with another Git repo and that was successful. The difference between them is that the first one with errors is a Private repo. But still on my local machine I am able to clone it but when I do the exact same thing on the Linux box, it gives me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clone over ssh first you will need to set up your ssh key with `ssh-keygen` A full walk through for generating keys and cloning over ssh can be found at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Once you do that you can use `git clone git@github.com/<repo path>`

Comment: hey thanks I tried with HTTP too, Full story over my comment I posted below my question. Can you please read and tell me what you think might be the issue?

Comment: My first guess is the authentication. Is it prompting you for login credentials when trying to clone from the private repository?

Comment: It was because the repo was private. I aksed her to make it public worked fine.